# How can I create a contextmenu which only displays on the cursor position when the container is clicked?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I tried using the code below to set up a contextmenu which only displays when the container div is clicked. But I am pretty messed up. If it helps here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippB/SMKMW/1/.

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var contextmenu = document.getElementById("contextmenu");

container.onclick = function() {contextmenu()} ;
contextmenu.style.display = "none";

function contextmenu(event) {
    if (contextmenu.style.display == "none") {
        contextmenu.style.display = "block";
        contextmenu.style.left = event.pageX + "px";
        contextmenu.style.top = event.pageY + "px";
    }
    else {
        contextmenu.style.display = "none";
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of strange things going on, so it isn't entirely clear to me what you're after.

- You have 2 different variables named 'contextmenu'.  The first is when you do a `getElementById`, the second when you define the `contextmenu` function.
- Your JS Fiddle example doesn't match your example above, and it contains an error in the IF statement (you only use 1 `=` not 2).  In fact, your JSFiddle example is very different from your above example
- In your example, the only content inside `container` is `contextmenu`, but you start it off with `display: none`, so it's hard to know what to click to get it to show.

Try this updated version of your JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/SMKMW/2/)

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var contextmenuElement = document.getElementById("contextmenu");

container.onclick = function() {contextmenu()} ;
contextmenuElement.style.display = 'none';

function contextmenu(event) {

    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    if (contextmenuElement.style.display == "block") {
        contextmenuElement.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        contextmenuElement.style.display = "block";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few problems:

- It looks like you're **wrapping your click handler with an unnecessary function**.

  Try defining your onclick handler using:

  ```
  container.onclick = contextmenu;
  ```
- You've also **named your handler function and reference to your DOM element the same**: `contextmenu`. Rename one of them.
- Your **comparison for the display is incorrect** (and is an assignment instead). It should be:

  ```
  if (contextmenuElement.style.display == "block") {
  ```
- Your **initial assignment of the container style doesn't set the value to a string**. It should be:

  ```
  contextmenu.style.display = 'none';
  ```

After making those changes, you'll notice that your container's not clickable. That's because it's got **no visible contents and doesn't have a width or height**. You might want to set those, or use CSS `visibility` instead of `display` to hide/show the element.

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNnym/) that works (I've added explicit height/width properties and a background color to the container to see what's going on).

Answer (score 1):

you should wrap string value by using quotations:

```
contextmenu.style.display = "none";
```

you should not define one `name` for a `Variable` and a `Function`:

```
var contextmenu // and function 
contextmenu()  // throw syntax error;
```

apart from this when an element is hidden, you cannot click on it, its better to create another element for calling the function and display a hidden element.